# python urllib randomly appearing HTTP Error 405:

Tags: python, urllib, http-status-code-405

Hello knowledgeable people,

I'm writing a code to grab some information from some subpages of a specific website.

The following three lines of code are working in around 8 of 10 cases (while using the same link/URL which is as well posted). But in two out of ten cases I'm getting the error 'HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: '.

I have no clue why the webpage is rejecting my request sometimes and sometimes not.
And even more important: How may I rebuild this code to get the answer for sure without an error message? (even if it takes more time)

```
import urllib

link = 'https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/128433102?utm_medium=email&utm_source=system&utm_campaign=fulfillment_update&savedSearchId=116004747&immoTypeId=2&PID=113689187&referrer=ff_listing&utm_content=fulfillment_item#/'

f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I solved it myself:

1. the request within a "try"
2. a dict in which I write for each url if it worked or not
3. a while-loop in which I'm repeating it for the url for which it did not work the previos times.
4. and a break after there is no url left without a successful web scrabbing.
5. In between I'm transforming the data in the way I need it.

Probably not a extraordinary tactic.

Today it took 9 rounds in the loop before 17 links all have been srabbed.

I'm still curious about the reason of the failure and a direct solution. But my solution gets the data I want without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

*HTTP Error 405*

[405](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) is *Method Not Allowed*. Most probably you send `GET` request when `POST` was expected or `POST` when `GET` was expected.

*get the answer for sure without an error message? (even if it takes more time)*

You should first ask resource what method(s) it does support. For this [OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) HTTP verb is used. After getting response you might check what methods are allowed in headers (under `Allow`) and sent correct request.

Simple example of sending `OPTIONS` using `urllib.request`

```
import urllib.request
req_obj = urllib.request.Request("https://www.example.com",method="OPTIONS")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req_obj)
print(response.headers['Allow'])
```

output

```
OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST
```

Comment: But it is working in 80% of the cases. Do you want to tell me that in one second the method is allowed and in the next second it is not anymore?

Comment: @ThomasR methods allowed are defined for each url, they generally should not be time-dependent

Comment: @ Daweo That is what I thought. But then your answer is not an answer to my question, is it?
Your code snippet with my link is producing ALWAYS the output: "GET, HEAD, POST". (I tried it 100 times in a loop.)
But still my code "urllib.request.urlopen(link)" is failing 20% of the times with the "HTTP Error 405:".